# Could not load file or assembly in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services

I've created one project for report localization, which consists one class file and three .resx files. In class file, I wrote code which find appropriate .resx file, depending on culture, and read value for given key.

After that, i build up project, copy the .dll into "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies**" and change RSPreviewPolicy.config, where I've added one new PermissionSet for Report localization and one CodeGroup tag giving Permission to .dll.

Next step I did was creating report, referencing .dll and write one expression to test localization.

I got following error:

"Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly

I'm obviously missing something, but I can't figure out what?

Does somebody has idea of what to do?

Comment: You can get detailed error message using Assembly Binding Log Viewer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the answer. Problem were permissions for viewing report in Visual Studio Preview mode.

First of all, I was putting *dll* (with localization class) into next location:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies**.

After that, I needed to change `RSPreviewPolicy.config` file, that exists in same folder location, to apply some security permissions.

In question, I mentioned that I've added one **PermisionSet**, but now I am sure there is no need for that.

I've just changed two **CodeGroup** section, which have `Execution` permission level, to have `FullTrust` permission level, like this:

```
<CodeGroup
    class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions"
    Description="This code group grants default permissions for code in report expressions and Code element. ">
    .
    .
    .
</CodeGroup>
<CodeGroup
    class="FirstMatchCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Description="This code group grants MyComputer code Execution permission. ">
    .
    .
    .          
</CodeGroup>
```

Regarding your version of Visual Studio, you must choose appropriate folder path:

- for VS 2015 --- *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies*
- for VS 2013 --- *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies*
- for VS 2010 --- *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies*

Comment: Many thanks for this! I've been struggling with loading assembly issue, and following these steps worked!

Comment: Many thanks to you ... You saved my time. been struggling with the same issue.